# Read and update json file data every second

Tags: android, json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am reading a JSON file from a web server and want to update my data every second. I am changing my style sheet with the data of JSON file.

I apply this course in ionic 3.

```
public level;
public sensor;


constructor(public navCtrl: NavController , public peopleData:PeopleDataProvider) {
peopleData.getPeople().subscribe(waterlevel => {

    this.level = (waterlevel.val/1000)*100;
    this.levelStyles = {height: (waterlevel.val/1000)*100+'%' };
```

Can anyone tell me how to update this code every second?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the web API that you are using. If it supports websockets, then your life will be much easier as you do not need to poll data every second. Just do a google search "How to get real-time updates from a web end point supporting websockets in android?".

If your web APi is an http, then you will have to poll every second (which is not recommended and is a bad practice). In this situation you can use a third-party service like [streamdata.io](https://streamdata.io) to convert your http web api in to something that pushes update to your JSON file using [Server Sent Events (SSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events).

Here's in an example on their website how to use it in android projects:

[android-server-sent-events](https://streamdata.io/blog/github-android-server-sent-events/)